# How do I apply a patch from gnus to a git repo?

Tags: magit, gnus

I've got an email with a dozen `.patch` files attached in gnus. I can save them to e.g. `~/Downloads` and then apply them with `magit-patch-apply-popup`, but considering that I've got gnus open on the left (and I can open the patch in its own buffer by putting my cursor over it and pressing `c`) and the magit summary buffer on the right, I would think that I could just apply the patch right there. But I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: `debbugs-gnu-apply-patch` from [debbugs.el](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/debbugs.html) might be of interest. Although I find it not quite adequate; I have some [work-in-progress replacements](https://github.com/npostavs/emacs.d/blob/e7e365d28b88a078f41aa2d6902bf5574cb803e6/elisp/np-utils.el#L116) in my .emacs.d/.

Comment: @npostavs In the same way that Emacs provides "some" features. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer via this blog post: [Use Gnus to apply patch sent by `git send-email`](http://blog.binchen.org/posts/use-gnus-to-apply-patch-sent-by-git-send-email.html).

Basically, I put point on the email in the gnus Summary buffer, then do `O m` and save the email somewhere. Then in magit I do `w m` and it will apply the patch.

Unfortunately for me this lost some commit info because the patches were sent from Gmail which formats patches incorrectly. So I just saved all the attached patches into the root of the git repo, selected them all (`C-SPC`) in the magit buffer, then did `w w` to apply them all individually. Then deleted the `.patch` files.

Comment: If you have them highlighted in the magit status buffer, `k` deletes  them.